# Using ngResources to make JSON without qutotes

Tags: javascript, json

Hello I have problem with posting JSON to my rest API. ngResource is passing string with qutes it is look like

> {"name" : "Jan", "surname" : "Kowalski", "position" : "{"positionid":0}, "id" : 1 }"

but I need it in this way

> {"name" : "Jan", "surname" : "Kowalski", "position" : {"positionid":0}, "id" : 1 }

here is my code in jsp :

```
controller('addNewWorkerController',    
['$scope','formService','positionlist',function($scope,formService,positionlist) {

 $scope.saveData=function () {

 var str=  "{positionID:"+$scope.formInfo.position+"}";
        $scope.position = str;
          window.alert(str);
        console.log($scope.formInfo);
        formService.save($scope.formInfo);
    }
```

my formService code

```
 service.factory('formService',['$resource',function($resource){ 

 return $resource('http://localhost:8080/workers',{},{
  save:{
    method:'POST'
  }  
}
)


 }]);
```

Comment: As a side note: Have you looked into `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: no, could you explain more?

Comment: That is because you are doing it like that.

Comment: Do you need to convert between JSON strings and native JavaScript objects?

Comment: Build your object which will be the JSON, and then pass that object into `JSON.stringify(myObject)`. That will return a valid JSON string.

Comment: @gcampbell - can you send a JS object as JSON?

Comment: still with qutoes.

Comment: @evolutionxbox You can only encode things like strings, numbers, booleans, and arrays, not things like functions.

Comment: @gcampbell - I didn't see the OP trying to encode a function... why would one do that?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Sorry, what I meant was to ask the OP if they simply needed `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you need to do this:

```
$scope.saveData=function () {
    var str =  {positionID : $scope.formInfo.position }; // <---instead of js object string convert it to js object.
    $scope.position = str;
    window.alert(str);
    console.log($scope.formInfo);
    formService.save($scope.formInfo);
}
```

Comment: not working it gives me {position: "0", name: "foo", surname: "bar", startWorkDate: Fri Jul 22 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time)}